# Drawing a segment with dashes

Tags: linux, graphics, drawing, lines

I need to draw an horizontal segment with dashes on it for a doc I'm writing. 
I need to subdivide the segment length this way: given `l`, then length of the segment and `n` the fraction of the remaining length at each step, the first dash should be at `first=l/n` from the left, the second at `1/n + (l-first)/n` and so on (until the division returns a number less than one)

What tool could I use to draw this automatically, without using a programming language?
Or... what script could do this?

I need and image in png/jpg as the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to do it programmitically, then maybe [Logo programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28programming_language%29) is your tool. it can also be done rather easily with `LATEX` and `TikZ` package, in this case you can consult with the [TEX-LATEX site](http://tex.stackexchange.com), also have a look at [library for image creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887428/scala-library-for-image-creation), all the answers there link to usefull resources, which could be a bit overkill for what you need, but will work. if it's not have to be done programmiticaly, you can just create the image with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org) or [InkScape](http://inkscape.org), though if you need to create many such dashed lines, it would be better to automate the process, and i don't know if these tools has *batch action* capability like photoshop.